# How to modify composable passed as parameter

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to apply styles and modifiers to composable that is passed to another composable as a parameter. Lets assume i want to add `Modifier.weight(1f)` to `title` and apply `color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant` to the `Text()` inside it, if present. Here is simplified example:

```
@Composable
fun EnableDisableRow(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    status: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    onEnableClick: () -> Unit,
    onDisableClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        title()
        // other code
    }
}
```

I tried to investigate how it is done with standard composables like `Button` but did not succeed. It is a bit too complecated.

With modifier i found a workaround using `Box` around `title()`. But maybe there is a better solution. For text style i did not find any solutions (editing parameter like `title: @Composable (color: Color) -> Unit` is defenetly not the right way)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If an answer was helpful to you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could mess around using [`LocalCompositionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal), which also is used by the Compose Framework to apply styles to Composables. However I think this won't work in case of Modifiers. They instead should be passed as a parameter, and [by convention](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers), each Composable should provide a Modifier parameter.

> It's a best practice to have all of your composables accept a modifier parameter, and pass that modifier to its first child that emits UI.

A simple approach is to require that the Composable that is being passed in provides parameters for setting a Modifier and Color like this:

```
@Composable
fun EnableDisableRow(
    title: @Composable (modifier: Modifier, color: Color) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    status: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    onEnableClick: () -> Unit,
    onDisableClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        title(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant
        )
        // other code
    }
}
```

Now, you could pass in a Composable like

```
@Composable 
fun TitleComposable(textModifier: Modifier = Modifier, textColor: Color = Color.Unspecified) {

    Text(
        text = "Title",
        modifier = textModifier,
        color = textColor
    )
}
```

---

If you want to test a `LocalCompositionProvider` approach, you can try it as follows:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides Color.Red) {
    title()
}
```

However, this only works for styling, not for setting a Modifier.

Comment: Tnaks for your answer. This approach is simple and straightforward, but in my opinion it adds overhead to the outer composable where my component is used. Do you know how to implement it with `LocalCompositionProvider`?

Comment: I edited my question, let me know if that works. This will however only work for color, and not for Modifiers. Also, it could affect some other Composables in the title() Compsoable as well. I would saying the overhead is negligible with the first approach.